# moduleNotFoundError: No module named 'aws_cdk' python windows

Tags: python, aws-cdk

I keep getting the same error of `aws-cdk` not being able to run on the code. I first thought it was case sensitivity but that did not solve the issue. I think it may be a path location issue but I have already done the installs through `npm` and the pip install of the `requirements txt`. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os

from aws_cdk import core as cdk
```

Terminal:
File `"C:\Users\aliai\Desktop\rekognition-video-people-blurring-cdk-main\my-project\app.py", line 4, in <module> import aws_cdk as cdk ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aws_cdk'`

Comment: You are using the `cdk init` command to create your project, right? Then you are activating the project's virtual environment before installing any modules, right?

Answer (score 0):

You should install aws_cdk module via pip, according to docs:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/work-with-cdk-python.html

Comment: I have done the pip install and it already says the requirement is met, any other ideas?

Comment: Do you use specified project environment? If you do, did you install for default global python environment or in your project environment?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).